# How do browsers render contents of a canvas element

Tags: javascript, html, web, html5-canvas

How does the browser render contents of the html canvas? Things like context.lineTo(x, y). There must be some component that converts all the function calls to pixel data. What I actually want to know is if there is some way to get this pixel data without actually rendering it somewhere.

I want to know if we can run some sort of stand alone javascript engines (v8) and pass javascript code to it and get pixel data as the output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What I actually want to know is if there is some way to get this pixel
>   data without actually rendering it somewhere.

Natively no, there is no way to get the pixel data besides from using a canvas (technically a bitmap) to rasterize the vector data (paths) in the browser.

The browsers typically use the underlying graphic core system (ie. DirectX etc.) to do the rasterization. We have no access to this through the browser (nor on top of V8/node.js unless you modify it). This sub-system will handle all the rasterizing of lines, circles, arcs and ellipses to pixels, as well as fill polygons and so forth, however not by building an array of point positions but by merely "walking" a slope (put simple of course - fill uses a different approach though based on line scanning).

For lines this means the current pixel will for example only be registered temporary as relative to the previous one, for circle/ellipses a pixel is typically in addition mirrored here and there. But in essence there is no registration of absolute or relative pixel positions that can be extracted after the rasterization took place.

If you are after an array with the *positions* of each pixel then you need to implement your own solution of some algorithm. But unless you need that for a very special reason I cannot see why you would not use the canvas which would do this much faster for you, or just work in vector space directly, rasterize them only when needed.

You can use JavaScript to implement this yourself using the various line algorithms and what have you out there. See markE's excellent answer for a starter. I also did this for a [Retro-Canvas](https://github.com/epistemex/retro-context-canvas) a while back which you can have a look at to see the algorithms used in JavaScript. They are optimized as well.

In addition to that you would need to implement a [2D matrix](https://github.com/epistemex/transformation-matrix-js) for rotation, scaling and translation if you want the flexibility/compatibility of the canvas.

One thing you need to be aware of though is that with this approach you will eliminate *anti-aliasing* which is important for a smooth looking result. This is something you'll have to add on top if you need that (you could also try to sync your internal lines with those drawn on canvas but they would need to be the exact same which probably at that stage can get you into trouble as Linux, Mac, Windows etc. uses different graphic sub-systems with possibly minor variations in result) and will require you to register additional pixels with different colors/alpha values.

**Some resources:**

- [Bresenham line and circle algorithm](http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/technical/graphics-programming-and-theory/bresenhams-line-and-circle-algorithms-r767)
- [EFLA line algorithm](http://www.edepot.com/algorithm.html)
- [Bresenham ellipse algorithm](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/awf/graphics/bres-ellipse.html)
- [Polygon fill algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scanline_rendering)

These are the basic building blocks for any typical polygonal shape (an arc is part of a circle so I didn't include this, but there exists optimized approaches for this out there).

You can in addition use Catmull/Rom and [cardinal splines](https://github.com/epistemex/cardinal-spline-js) as well as [Bezier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve) which is typically implemented as 2. order (quadratic, one control point) and 3. order (two control points), if you want the ability to make smoother shapes, font outlines and so forth.

Another possible approach is to draw the shapes on an off-screen canvas in white color on black or transparent background, then scan each line and put each pixel you find with it's position and relative color (to alpha) in an array. However, this will not give you *continuous* lines, just each pixel's position whatever they are a part of...

Comment: +1 Nice answer @Ken Fyrstenberg -- and welcome back!  BTW, I checked out your artwork linked in your profile...Impressive! I wish my artwork could get better than stick-figures, but I was not so blessed.

Comment: I wanted to send pixel data of one canvas to another canvas. So from this I understand that there is no frame buffer associated with an html canvas. If I need a frame buffer I would need to use the buffer of the display system (like the X window system), right? Emitting signals such as 'line' from the server and redrawing them in the client works fine. But the same can't be done for canvases containing non-vector graphics (jpeg images for eg). In those cases having a frame buffer is the only way to go I guess

Comment: Questions : Will implementing a frame buffer on top of nodejs result in heavy performance penalty? Also, will using an off screen canvas give an improved performance over using an on-screen canvas? (since you don't have to actually draw it to the screen). Thanks a lot for the great answer :)

Comment: @lonesword Broadcasting drawing commands still works for commands that draw in raster form. For example you could .emit a serialized version of drawImage like this: `{ command:'drawImage', params{ src:'http//mySite.com/images/myImage.png', x:20, y:30},  timestamp:performance.now() }`  I suggest this because broadcasting things as large as a pixel-buffer *definitely will degrade performance*.  My node.js philosophy is: "Just hit'em with a few bits at a time". Good luck with your project!

Comment: @markE triple thanks markE! I'm just poppin´ in between the "battles" :) Oh, [simple lines can be very expressive on their own](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_NMYWQmURsM)!

Comment: @lonesword basically what markE says here. I would suggest you define your own simple "protocol" or a JSON object. The image data, when needed, can be serialized. The benefit with off-screen canvas is that it does not need to be included in the screen refresh. X-windows work inmuch the same way, but IIRC uses a pure byte stream (which would be my personal choice). Things like f.ex. VNC sends image regions of changed areas and so forth but here you could not extract exactly what had changed (you would not know if a line or something else was drawn).

Comment: @KenFyrstenberg. LOL + Wow! Now that's line art!

Comment: @KenFyrstenberg Why would vnc not detect if a line is drawn?

Comment: @markE Ok now that had not occured to me! Thanks! ^_^

Thanks a lot guys. I have way more clarity on this than when I started. Emitting signals as markE said looks like the best option :)

Comment: @lonesword it will base the changes on bitmap regional changes wheater they are a line, icon, text etc. - it sees all as a bitmap change (differential) and will try to capture the smallest region of change and transfer that as a bitmap block encoded in various ways (exception for VNC is of course key strokes and mouse position). The key here IMO is to establish a simple protocol/JSON definition that will allow you to use simple commands for drawing operations and byte streams/base-64 for pure bitmap data (ie. images).

Answer (score 5):

**The browser (or the graphics card) is just applying mathematical algorithms to set pixels.**

The results are stored in a backing array that Html Canvas maintains to keep the state of each of it's pixels.

Each canvas pixel is represented by a set of 4 elements in the canvas' pixel array. The 4 pixel set is the R,G,B,A values.  So a single red pixel would be represented by this set of 4 elements in the pixel array:

```
pixelArray=[...255,0,0,255...]  // where 255==red, 0==green, 0==blue, alpha==255
```

You don't get access to the browser's internal pixel-setting algorithms, but you can run the same algorithms to set the appropriate pixels.

Here's an outline of how to do that:

**Assume you have an array representing all pixels on an imaginary grid:**

```
var width=500;
var height=500;
var pixels=new Array(width*height);
```

**You can get the array element corresponding to any pixel like this:**

```
var x=200;
var y=30;
var arrayElement=y*width+x;
```

**You can set the array pixel-element like this:**

```
function setPixel(x,y,colorObject){
    pixels[y*width+x]=colorObject;
}

setPixel(100,50,{r:255,g:0,b:0,a:255});
```

**You can get the pixel setting for any [x,y] like this:**

```
function getPixel(x,y){
    return(pixels[y*width+x]);
}

var theColor=getPixel(100,50);
```

**Then you can set the pixels on a line segment connecting points [x0,y0] to [x1,y1] like this:**

```
// Refer to: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Bitmap/Bresenham's_line_algorithm#JavaScript

function bline(x0, y0, x1, y1) {
  var dx = Math.abs(x1 - x0), sx = x0 < x1 ? 1 : -1;
  var dy = Math.abs(y1 - y0), sy = y0 < y1 ? 1 : -1; 
  var err = (dx>dy ? dx : -dy)/2;        
  while (true) {
    setPixel(x0,y0);
    if (x0 === x1 && y0 === y1) break;
    var e2 = err;
    if (e2 > -dx) { err -= dy; x0 += sx; }
    if (e2 < dy) { err += dx; y0 += sy; }
  }
}
```

The other Html Canvas Path elements have similar algorithms that will calculate each [x,y] pixel that needs to be set along the path.

**Html Canvas Curve Paths**

Each curved Path element is defined by a mathematical equation. You can get each [x,y] along the curve by oversampling values at intervals using those equations.

For example, the formula to **fetch [x,y] points along a quadratic curve** at an interval (T) is as follows.  T is a value between 0.00 and 1.00 where T==0.00 is at the start of the curve and T==1.00 is at the end of the curve.

```
// Get [x,y] at interval T along a Quadratic Curve
var x = Math.pow(1-T,2) * startPt.x + 2 * (1-T) * T * controlPt.x + Math.pow(T,2) * endPt.x; 
var y = Math.pow(1-T,2) * startPt.y + 2 * (1-T) * T * controlPt.y + Math.pow(T,2) * endPt.y;
```

You must oversample intervals (T) along curves or you risk missing [x,y] points along that curve.  That's because unlike lines, curve formula do not fetch uniformly spaced points. Here's an example that oversamples with 1000 T waypoints between 0.00 and 1.00.

```
// Oversample T along a quadratic curve to be sure to catch all [x,y]
// Some pixels will harmlessly be set more than once, 
// but it's likely that all desired pixels will be set
for(var i=0;i<1000;i++){
    var T=i/1000;
    var x = Math.pow(1-T,2) * startPt.x + 2 * (1-T) * T * controlPt.x + Math.pow(T,2) * endPt.x; 
    var y = Math.pow(1-T,2) * startPt.y + 2 * (1-T) * T * controlPt.y + Math.pow(T,2) * endPt.y; 
    setPixel(x,y,color);
}
```

The formula to **Fetch [x,y] points along a cubic Bezier curve** is as follows.

```
// De Casteljau's algorithm which calculates points along a cubic Bezier curve
function getCubicBezierXYatT(startPt,controlPt1,controlPt2,endPt,T){
    var x=CubicN(T,startPt.x,controlPt1.x,controlPt2.x,endPt.x);
    var y=CubicN(T,startPt.y,controlPt1.y,controlPt2.y,endPt.y);
    return({x:x,y:y});
}

// cubic helper formula at T distance
function CubicN(T, a,b,c,d) {
    var t2 = T * T;
    var t3 = t2 * T;
    return a + (-a * 3 + T * (3 * a - a * T)) * T
    + (3 * b + T * (-6 * b + b * 3 * T)) * T
    + (c * 3 - c * 3 * T) * t2
    + d * t3;
}
```

The formula to **fetch [x,y] points along an Arc** at a specified radian angle is as follows.

```
// Trigonometry to calculate [x,y] at a specified angle
function get ArcXYatRadianAngle(centerX,centerY,radius,radianAngle){
    var x=centerX+radius*Math.cos(radianAngle);
    var y=centerY+radius*Math.sin(radianAngle);
}
```

**Html Canvas Operators**

Setting **globalAlpha** is as simple as setting the `alpha` element of any pixel to a desired value between 0 and 255 (between fully-transparent and fully-opaque).

Even the **globalCompsiteOperation** is relatively straightforward.

- Plot a new [x,y] pixel value to apply to the pixel array.
- Read the existing pixel value from the pixel array.
- Apply your desired compositing effect using of these options:

  - Keep the existing pixel value
  - Overwrite with the new pixel value
  - Set the alpha value of the pixel to 0 (make it transparent)

Hint: This method of comparing existing pixels with replacement pixels can also be used to apply Blending filters to your pixels! ;-)

**Clipping** is more difficult in that you must be sure you only apply new pixel values inside the specified clipping area.  You could use Calculus to determine the allowable drawing areas, but more straightforward would be to:

- You already have the first pixel array (call it the "drawing-array")
- Create a second pixel array to hold the pixels defined by the clipping path (call this second array the "clipping-array")
- When applying new pixels to the drawing-array, first consult the clipping array.  If the clipping-array pixel is SET then set the pixel in the drawing-array. If the clipping-array pixel is UNSET then don't alter that pixel in the drawing array.

Whew! Well that should get you started...Good luck with your project!

Comment: Brilliant explanation! I had tried doing the line drawing algorithms before and I do not think they are as fast as the ones internally used by the canvas. Is it simply because my algorithms are not optimized or is it because implementing it in javascript is slow?

Comment: As you've discovered, "manual" drawings will be slower than native browser drawings using the canvas element. That's because browser algorithms are hardware accelerated and optimized.

Comment: And I assume there is no way to access these internal functions even using nodejs or v8?

Comment: You can access the internal functions using the Canvas element(!). Otherwise these methods are indeed internal.